# How to update my global variables with information from a Google Geocoder async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, google-geocoder

I am using the Google Geocoder API to get coordinates given an address, and I currently have this function:

```
var latitude = 0;
var longitude = 0;

  const test = getGeocode(
    location[0].address,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  ).then(
    (response) => {
      latitude = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      longitude = longitude = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    },
  );
```

When I console.log the lat and long values inside of the const test, the values print correctly. However, I am unable to save these values into the longitude and latitude global variables as I need to. Is there anything I can do to save the long and lat values from my const test into global variables so that I can use them elsewhere? (My ultimate goal is to display the location of the long/lat on a map on my site.)

Comment: why do you think you are not able to save them? Could it be that where you are using them is outside the scope of the 'then', hence runs before the value areeven  set, you should use console.log() at both places where you are setting it and where you are using it

Comment: Is that code running directly on your webpage? If so, the global variables should be saved. Perhaps you should show more of your code, there might be a problem somewhere else. Are the variables definitely being declared in the global scope (zero indentation level)?

Comment: To David, the variables are declared in the global scope. Also to vaira, I understand what you're saying, but I need to get the values for use outside of the "then" scope, so I wanted to know if there was any way to do that